# duplicates in mapreduce program output?

Tags: hadoop

I get many duplicate values in my output, so I have implemented a reduce function as shown below, but still this reduce works as an identity function, that is there is no difference in output even if I have a reduce or not. What's wrong with my reduce function?

```
       public class search 
{      
    public static String str="And";
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> 
    {
        String mname="";
        public void configure(JobConf job)
        {
             mname=job.get(str);
             job.set(mname,str);
        }

        private Text word = new Text();
        public Text Uinput =new Text("");
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
        {

            String mapstr=mname;
            Uinput.set(mapstr);
            String line = value.toString();
            Text fdata = new Text();

            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                fdata.set(line);

                if(word.equals(Uinput))
                output.collect(fdata,new Text(""));
            }

        }
    } 

    public static class SReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> 
    {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
        {

            boolean start = true;
            //System.out.println("inside reduce   :"+input);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (values.hasNext()) 
            {
                if(!start)

                start=false;
                sb.append(values.next().toString());

            }
            //output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
            output.collect(key, new Text(sb.toString()));
        }
    }
```

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

```
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(search.class);
    conf.setJobName("QueryIndex");
    //JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), WordCount.class);
    conf.set(str,args[0]);

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    //conf.setCombinerClass(SReducer.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(SReducer.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);



    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path("IIndexOut"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("searchOut"));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305435/hadoop-inverted-index-without-recurrence-of-file-names

Comment: Hi Matt, I have gone through that post, but it didnt solve my problem. That's why I have posted my own.

Answer (score 1):

I have not looked at the code thoroughly, but one thing I am certain about is the boolean variable **start** is useless here, the code below ***if (!start)*** should be in brackets to de-dup data, otherwise you just end up writing all the data in reducer which you receive from mapper.

```
 public static class SReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> 
{
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
    {

        boolean start = true;
        //System.out.println("inside reduce   :"+input);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (values.hasNext()) 
        {
            if(!start)
            {
               start=false;
               sb.append(values.next().toString());
            }

        }
        //output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        output.collect(key, new Text(sb.toString()));
    }
}
```

Or an optimal reduce method would be to just :-

```
public static class SReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> 
  {
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException 
{

   //System.out.println("inside reduce   :"+input);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(values.next().toString());

    //output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    output.collect(key, new Text(sb.toString()));
}
```

}

As you only care about the 1st value of the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not set this reducer as the actual reduce function to be used? That is done using

```
job.setReducerClass().
```

If you don't set the class as your class, then the default reducer is used. You should do the following:

```
job.setReducerClass(SReducer.class)
```

please post your main function so that we can verify that.

Comment: I did that, I have also posted it above, please check it.

Comment: are you sure you're reading the latest output? I suggest that you delete all previous output files and run the job again. What are you running your job on btw?

Comment: its a search engine program, so indexout is the output from the inverted index implementation, in this searching step i just have to search for a keyword and display the results(where im getting duplicates)

Comment: Im deleting the previous output file everytime, before running the program again.

Comment: and Im running my job on my laptop, using ubuntu

Comment: I am not able to figure out what it is, but I can offer a suggestion. You could try looking into the log files, and checking what's happening in each reducer. All the info. should be available on log files. It might be better to use few reducers, so that you don't have to read through a lot of log files

Answer (score 0):

use @override annotation before map and reduce functions. So that you can be very sure, that you are overriding the base class method.